# how can join angular and google map together?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am using angularjs as MVC of my web site and in this project I most work with google-map. i searched in the internet and find this library for working with google-map in angularjs :

- [allen hwking ng-Map](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps)
- [angular-ui map library](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/)

but both of them are weak in documentation an samples.
is there any other library or is there a good documentation for these library?
it is necessary for me to create map object (polygons, markers, ...) dynamically ...

Comment: just use simple google maps v3 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/
here's a sample project i did back then https://github.com/aishwat/storeLocator

Comment: i use this but is not handy and need expert person ....

Comment: what is the specific problem?

Comment: specific problem is asking for a good simple and handy library.... count down ???? why????

Comment: whats your problem man???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this one
[angular-google-maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/use)

Easy to install and easy to use.
Let me know!!

Comment: thanks for your comment but i see this before... but all of examples are static and tag oriented ... and there is not enough code for dynamic working